# Ideal Setup for vSphere Hypervisor

Tags: networking, memory, vmware, raid, hypervisor

I just picked up a Dell R720 for my company, it's got plenty of resources where I feel I can run multiple VM's at the same time. Here are the specs.

- Intel Xeon E5-2620 (2)
- 8GB DIMM (8)
- 146GB SAS 15K (2)
- 4 Gigabit NIC ports
- 2 Gigabit NIC card
- Dell PERC

I wanted to run three to four virtual machines with the VMware vSphere Hypervisor.

**How could I best implement the install of Hypervisor along with the 3-4 virtual machines I want to load?**

Should I RAID-0 the two SAS drives and then do 2 virtual drives along the raid? Then install Hypervisor on a 80GB virtual partition and then leave the other 212 GB for virtual machines? Then I would have 1 NIC provide for the Hypervisor, 1 NIC provide for the DRAC, and the other 4 provide for VM's.

Or should I purchase an additional 4 drives like VMware's site recommends and RAID-1 the two 146GB drives and then RAID-5 the rest?

Comment: Did you actually ever install vSphere? IIRC, you can’t really choose any partitioning schemes. Also, RAID 0 is really a no-go in enterprise deployments.

Comment: No, I've watched a few videos on VMware's website and YouTube. I agree on the RAID-0 thing but can't imagine another alternative at the moment.

Comment: I still don’t see how it would be necessary. If you’re concerned about the amount if contiguous memory, don’t be. Apparently (can’t verify now), VMFSs can be grown by adding extents on different drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but there's no answer selected and I thought it might help someone else if not the original poster.

First, figure out how much space you're going to need on the VMs.  If you're coming up short, you may need bigger or more hard drives.  I typically will do a raid 1 or raid 10 datastore (using 15k sas drives) on which I store the OS partitions of my VMs.  I then do some sort of expandable array such as RAID5 (using sata 7200 drives) that I use for virtual disks that are just file storage, or data (non-OS related) that I'm not as concerned about the speed.

I will tell you, one thing I wish I had known the first time I installed VMWare was, that the system files used to boot ESXi are very small.  Install ESXi to a usb thumb drive.  [These work great.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005FYNSZA)  I've heard you only need 4GB, but those 16GB's are so highly recommended and the price isn't bad, so I went with those.  The reason this will be important in your setup, is you only have two drives, so if you choose to use some of one of the 146GB drive's space, when you go to upgrade to the next version of ESXi down the road, it will want to repartition that whole drive.  That means if you have a datastore on that drive, it'll wipe it out just to do an upgrade.  If you install to the usb, when you do an upgrade, you'll just upgrade to the usb drive and it won't effect your datastores at all.

As for NIC setup, I usually refer to [Kendrick Coleman's blog](http://www.kendrickcoleman.com/index.php/Tech-Blog/vsphere-host-nic-design-6-nics.html) and customize for my needs based on one of his designs.

Last but not least, MAKE SURE YOU DOCUMENT ALL OF YOUR SETTINGS, and keep them somewhere you'll be able to find them when you do an upgrade in a year.

Hope that's helpful advice for anyone new to VMWare.